# Solitaire game with all cards up in 5 rows of 10 cards each?

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire, free-cell

What is this game?

The rules are:
**Goal** - To create four "foundations" from all the cards.
**Foundations** - Build up in suit from Ace to King.
**Initial Tableau** - 50 cards in 5 rows of 10 each and two cards on the side.  All cards are faced up.
**Actions** - You can move the cards around alternating between red and black in descending numerical order.
**Temporary spaces** - You can have up to three extra cards on the side.

Comment: That sounds a lot like freecell with a different amount of rows

Comment: The synonym for "increasing" is "ascending", not "a sending".

Answer (score 1):

The game sounds like [Seahaven Towers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seahaven_Towers). [Here is a JavaScript version of the game](https://greenfelt.net/sht). The one clarification is that you may have four extra cards on the side. A short explanation of the rules, from the link above.

> Sea Haven Towers is a solitaire game created by Art Cabral and is similar to Freecell, Eight Off, and Baker's Game.
>
> There are 4 temporary spaces and 4 foundations above the 10 columns of the tableau. Foundations are build up in suit from Ace to King. Temporary spaces can hold one card at a time.
>
> The bottom card of each column is available for play. It may be moved to a temporary space, the foundation, or another column building downward in suit. Empty columns may be filled only by a King.
>
> To improve the game play, multiple cards may be dragged at once as long as there are enough empty temporary spaces such that the move could be made by moving the cards individually.

Comment: No, this game is nothing like what's been described in the question.